# YouTube asking to "Load unsafe scripts" for all videos

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I have to click the shield icon and tell Chrome to `"Load unsafe scripts"` every time I want to watch a video, which is starting to get a little annoying.

I reinstalled the latest version of Chrome, I have cleared all browsing data and have no extensions installed; but still have the same problem.

The console is showing me this message:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTWKbfoikeg' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://r1---sn-aiglln7l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&pl=17&…DB.DC19A74AF19185A2E5641AE8FFF61A4E85A607B2&c=WEB&cver=html5&range=0-65535'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Does anyone know how to make it stop?

Comment: Is the date/time correct on your computer?

Comment: Date and time is correct